# Total Arrangements in 6 character password if NO repetition is allowed and its Not Case Sensitive

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

6 character password must contain 3 digits, 2 letters and 1 special character

Assuming their are 7 special characters, REPETITION IS NOT ALLOWED, The password is NOT Case sensitive, how many ORDERED arrangements are there?

Is my Solution Correct?:

10c3 . 26c2 . 7c1 . 6! = 196 560 000 combinations

or Should it be 10p3 . 26p2 . 7p1 = 3276000 combinations? since you use perms to find the ordered arrangements.

Comment: It seems the first answer is correct: once you pick the items from each array (i.e. you pick which numbers, letters and which special character you want), then you have a new "group" of items (these six things that you picked). You have six spots, so you pick one of the six things (a letter, number, or the special character), and you move onto the next space, which has $5$ options. You iterate, and you get $6!$, so that's the final thing you need to multiply by.

Comment: @scoopfaze can you explain to me why the second solution wouldn't be correct?

Comment: For one thing, you would be permuting the elements you choose, but not where they go. In other words, you would force one arrangement of letters/numbers/character while disregarding the rest. Generally, I would avoid using permutations, as they can always be calculated by looking at the "spaces" of whatever you're trying to fill.

Comment: Also, $10$P$3$ just doesn't make a whole lot of sense. You're essentially saying: "I have three spots, and I have ten elements to choose from." This gets back to the problem I highlighted above: you'd be restricting the orderings of your numbers/letters/characters.

Answer (score 1):

As scoopfaze indicated in the comments, your first approach is correct.  Your second approach is the answer to a different question:

> In how many ways can a password of length six be formed if it has three distinct decimal digits, two distinct lowercase letters, and one of seven special characters that appear *in that order*?

We can fill the first three slots with three distinct decimal digits in $P(10, 3) = 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8$ ways, the next two slots with distinct lowercase letters in $P(26, 2) = 26 \cdot 25$ ways, and the final slot with one the seven special characters in $P(7, 1) = 7$ ways.  Therefore, the number of passwords with three distinct decimal digits, two distinct lowercase letters, and one of seven special characters that appear in that order is $$P(10, 3)P(26, 2)P(7, 1) = 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 26 \cdot 25 \cdot 7$$
Notice that we could also write the answer to this question in the following way:
$$\binom{10}{3}3!\binom{26}{2}2!\binom{7}{1}1!$$
Here is the rationale: Choose three distinct decimal digits, arrange them in the first three positions, choose two distinct lowercase letters, arrange them in the next two positions, choose one of the seven special characters, arrange it in the final position.

Notice that we are only allowing the digits to appear in the first three positions, the letters to appear in the next two positions, and the special character to appear in the last position.  This is different from the question you wish to answer, where the digits, letters, and special characters may appear in any of the positions.

> In how many ways can a password of length six be formed if it has three distinct decimal digits, two distinct lowercase letters, and one of seven special characters?

We can choose three distinct decimal digits, two distinct letters, and one special character, then arrange the six selected objects in
$$\binom{10}{3}\binom{26}{2}\binom{7}{1}6!$$
ways.